# How to correctly copy the buffer of memory?

Tags: c++, memory, memcpy

I need to copy buffer (for undo states) before making changes.
So, the classic code looks like:

```cpp
byte *buf = NULL;
byte *oldbuf = NULL;

buf = new byte[100];
//do something with buf

//Here I need to copy "buf" to "oldbuf"
oldbuf = new byte[100];
memcpy(oldbuf, buf, 100);

delete[]buf;
buf = new byte[50];
//next do some with buf
```

It's works fine, but take some time for "memcpy".
Can I copy buffer by pass pointer? Somethink like this?:

```cpp
byte *buf = NULL;
byte *oldbuf = NULL;

buf = new byte[100];
//do something with buf

//Here I need to copy "buf" to "oldbuf"
oldbuf = buf;

buf = new byte[50];
//next do some with buf
```

Comment: _"It's works fine, but take some time for "memcpy""_ Unless you have access to some HW support for copying/moving memory blocks, you can't avoid that.

Comment: Given your first snippet, the second one looks quite reasonable (and an obvious optimization). Did you try it and fail somehow? If so, please post a [mre].

Comment: Please get yourself an up to date C++ book. We are not using `new[]` and `delete[]` in this current millennium.

Comment: @n.m. Is that recomendation for smart ponters?

Comment: @StoryTeller I scary to catch memory leaks with second method

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Comment: @GiovaLomba std::vector would be a good start, smart pointers can come later.

Comment: @user3226859 - A leak is when no pointer points at a memory block, and that block isn't released. In your snippet `oldbuf` still points at the block. If this worries you, you can use some ready made tools to manage it, such as `std::vector`.

Comment: you can use std::copy , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Answer (score 4):

> I need to copy buffer (for undo states) before making changes. So, the classic code looks like: ...

No, the classic c++ code to use ever looked like

```
std::vector<byte> buf(100);
//do something with buf

//Here I need to copy "buf" to "oldbuf"
std::vector<byte> oldbuf = buf;

buf = std::vector<byte>(50);
//next do some with buf
```

That was working even before the 1st c++ standard was released.

---

Of course `std::vector<byte> oldbuf = buf;` involves to copy the contents sequentially, which takes some time. If there's any optimization to do this using HW capabilities, you should be faithful that the compiler will emit the necessary instructions to do that.

---

For the current c++ standard you could use [`std::move()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) to avoid making a copy of the original `buf`:

```
std::vector<byte> oldbuf = std::move(buf);
buf = std::vector<byte>(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be copying the reference and not the contents at that memory location. Buf as it is, is simply a reference.

Comment: You probably should show what's the right way to do it in your question also. But I am afraid there's no standard way to avoid the OP's worries about copying.

Comment: Used memcpy and clean up after. You are only copying 100 bytes it shouldn't be noticeably slower.

Comment: @Jonathan 100 it's just for example. I'm working with huge arrays like 8000*7000 :)